# How to create a photo gallery with Cloudinary (and jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, image-gallery, picasa, cloudinary

I have developed a web application (jQuery) many years ago, which operated the Picasa Web Album galleries (PWA) where teachers can easily select their own pictures among those they wanted to integrate educational exercises for classes. Now Google has announced the death of Picasa scheduled for 1 May 2016! Although the API is not completely removed on that date, the functionality will be reduced.

In short, I have to find something else to continue this project.

This is where I found Cloudinary.com, a SaaS clearly very powerful to load images, transform them and then use them in web applications.

However, if there are tons of examples of implementation of the functions of upload, I do not see how to manage a structured gallery photos albums (folders).

Someone who already put it out? Can share some code end to put me on the right track? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation page](http://cloudinary.com/documentation) where you can find all supported frameworks.
You will need to first [migrate](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520662-How-can-I-bulk-upload-my-images-) your images to Cloudinary.
Then you will be able to serve it using Cloudinary composite URLs, for example:
[image]
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_150,c_scale,a_15/sample.jpg
A jQuery plugin is also available to help you intuitively construct the URLs and embed it in your application.
"Out of the box" gallery is not yet offered by Cloudinary although it is on the roadmap.